# How to click menubar option in a website?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I want to code to click a menu in a website.

```vb
Sub SearchBot()
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ckt_No As String
    ckt_No = Range("A2").Value
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
    ie.Navigate "http://gamit.web.att.com/gamitx/welcome.htm"

    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("yui-gen1").Focus
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("yui-gen1").Click
      
    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Stop 'Press SHIFT + F9 and examine the window...
```

The menu
[image: Menu in web page]

while inspect the menu I got the HTML Code
[image: HTML Code]

VBA didn't throw any error, but it does not click the menu.

After running the code the menu looks like this
[image: After code Run]

I have Microsoft Internet control, Microsoft HTML object library functions in my VBA editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try navigating to the `href` of the child `a` tag (getting the parent by its id)

```
ie.navigate2 HTMLDoc.querySelector("#yui-gen1 a").href
```

Comment: @ QHarr..... Awesome :) :) ..... Super...!!!    This code works fine. Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, but I can't test it as your url is not working for me
`HTMLDoc.getElementById("yui-gen1").nextPageElement.Click`

Comment: Thanks for the reply..... while using this code I got  Error like "Object doesn't support this property or method"